# Blender is not rendering the whole of animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm having a lot of trouble rendering my animation. It looks fine in all modes except render mode, and when I render a scene only fragments of the render show.

- iMac
- 3,2 GHz Intel Core i5
- AMD Radeon R9 M380 2048 MB

Here is the link to the downloadable project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vbL3ypSbnbAPhmhHtKgcicL1Mgj-fxdu

Comment: please share on another site, it looks like we need approval for this one

Comment: Hi, sorry had the permissions set wrong. It should work now

Comment: Well, I can see everything in every scenario... What's your Blender version? Do you have the ability to test your scene on another computer?

Comment: The version is 2.79. Would I need to upgrade to a higher version? Is it the graphics card? Or lack there of?

Comment: Welcome, Shaun Tyler. Use this internal uploader: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your world material was completely black which causes the scene to be very black without heavy lighting. In addition there was no material applied to your smoke sim domain. It seems a bit unintuitive, but the material for the smoke needs to be on the domain and not  the emission surface or particle system. Please let me know if these tips help you get to where you need.

[image]

Comment: Good morning Aglet

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. This is my first ever 3D project on any software so that's why it seems very unintuitive. Your explination is great. I' just having a problem with finding the nodes and changes for the smoke. I'm not sure what the protocol is about this forum but would by chance could you send me your updated project file for the animation so I can see what you have done? If you can't i completely understand. Thanks again.